# Nuxt js check endpoint exists

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

How to check if endpoint exists in nuxt js? For example this URL: https://www.google.com/favicon.ico

```
async asyncData({ app, params, env, error, store }) {
      var _icon = "https://www.google.com/favicon.ico";
      try {
         var result = await app.$axios(_icon);
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
      }

}


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7RT5K.png
```

Comment: error: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7RT5K.png

Answer (score 0):

You forget "$get" when you used "$axios"

```
async asyncData({ app, params, env, error, store }) {
      var _icon = "https://www.google.com/favicon.ico";
      try {
         var result = await app.$axios.$get(_icon);
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
      }

}
```